# Automate OAuth authorization for my own account in Youtube Data API v3

Tags: oauth, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a web application wherein I want to allow specific users, admins of the site, to upload videos through my app to my own youtube channel. I don't want to give them my account credentials, but authorize them to upload videos on my channel. I am really stuck here.

**What I have tried** -

1. Tried a service account, and later found out that Youtube API doesn't support service accounts. It just throws Error 401 - Unauthorized.
2. I can save the refresh token after one-time authorization, but the problem is my app will be deployed on EC2 server and there's really not an option of opening something in a browser, so I won't be able to authorize anything on the server.
3. Through the help of OAuth Playground, I got a refresh token which I used as a hardcoded value and it worked fine, but I really am looking for a better solution than this, this is my last resort.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 2.  create a refresh token localy on your own machine then upload it to the server.  there is really no better option

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641250/does-google-oauth2-0-support-an-oauth-flow-for-a-resource-owner-password-credent

Comment: If you don't want to manually upload a token, you could also create a small client-side app that does the routine of obtaining and uploading the token for you.